Magento 2 Checkout Not Working Due to CSP Blocking Inline Scripts, Including Payment Gateway
I am experiencing an issue with Magento 2 where the checkout page is not loading correctly. Upon investigating, it appears that the Content Security Policy (CSP) is blocking inline scripts, which seems to be preventing the checkout from functioning properly.
In addition to the general checkout issue, I've noticed that my payment gateway's inline script is also being blocked.
This is how my console looks like.

Upon investigating further, it appears that CSP will not allow executing inline scripts unless I add a nonce to the script tag like this:
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="<?php echo $nonce; ?>">
    // Your inline JavaScript code here
</script>

I have also gone through the official documentation, but I haven't had any luck resolving this issue.

I am facing the same issue, are you able to resolve this issue ?
please update on this

$secureRenderer->renderTag will generate a NONCE automatically to go with your inline-script. Find each line on the checkout with 
Here’s the working solution I found, thanks a million, Sumit! It really saved my day.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/374139/115908

script tag is deprecated on checkout in Magento 2.4.7, you can write script tag as per following
<?php $scriptString = <<<script
        require(['jquery'],function($){
 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
         console.log("Hello checkout");
    });
}); 
script;
    ?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?>


I wonder why this is not accepted answer. Magento 2 discourages the direct use of the 
This is fine, but really ugly. Since 2.4.7 it has been possible to get a nonce and attach it to your script which makes for much better readability and editability.  This is definitely the best of the answers here.

If you want to run the checkout page without these errors, there are a few things you need to do.
Before I write the methods, I want to warn you that disabling these rules is at your own risk!
There are two ways to fix this:

Just add in app/etc/env.php file, small config like this:
    'csp' => [
        'mode' => [
           'storefront_checkout_index_index' => [
              'report_only' => '1'
           ],
           'admin_sales_order_create_index' => [
             'report_only' => '1'
           ]
        ],
        'policies' => [
           'storefront_checkout_index_index' => [
             'scripts' => [
                 'inline' => '1'
             ]
           ],
           'admin_sales_order_create_index' => [
             'scripts' => [
                 'inline' => '1'
             ]
           ]
        ]
     ]



And after that run:
bin/magento app:config:import
bin/magento cache:clean


Create new module in app/code folder.
For example app/code/YourCompany/CheckoutCsp

a) Add registration.php - app/code/YourCompany/CheckoutCsp/registration.php
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'YourCompany_CheckoutCsp',
    __DIR__
);

b) Add module.xml in etc folder - app/code/YourCompany/CheckoutCsp/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourCompany_CheckoutCsp" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>

c) Add config.xml in etc folder too - app/code/YourCompany/CheckoutCsp/etc/config.xml
add this code:
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </mode>
            <policies>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <scripts>
                        <inline>1</inline>
                        <event_handlers>1</event_handlers>
                    </scripts>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </policies>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>

Then, run:
bin/magento module:enable YourCompany_CheckoutCsp
rm -rf pub/static/* && rm -rf var/cache/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f


@Pranay Kos
Hey,
Step 1: Create or Update CSP Whitelist Configuration
Create or update a module to adjust the CSP settings. Here’s how you can do it:
Create a Custom Module
If you don't have a custom module, create one. For this example, let's call it Meetanshi_CustomCSP.
Create the Module Directory Structure
app/code/Meetanshi/CustomCSP

├── etc
│   └── csp_whitelist.xml
├── registration.php
└── composer.json
Define the Module
File: app/code/Meetanshi/CustomCSP/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Meetanshi_CustomCSP" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>

Register the Module
File: app/code/Meetanshi/CustomCSP/registration.php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Meetanshi_CustomCSP',
__DIR__

);
Step 2: Update CSP Whitelist Configuration
File: app/code/Meetanshi/CustomCSP/etc/csp_whitelist.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
<policies>
<policy id="script-src">
<values>
<value id="custom-inline" type="inline">script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';</value>
            <!-- Add any additional sources here -->
</values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="style-src">
        <values>
            <value id="custom-inline" type="inline">style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';</value>
            <!-- Add any additional sources here -->
        </values>
    </policy>
</policies>
</config>

Step 3: Deploy the Module
Run the following commands to deploy the changes:
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:clean


Element 'value', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'inline' is not an element of the set {'host', 'hash'}.
It shows this error

getting same issue, @DhavalSolanki are you able to fix this issue, please help

hi my friend @DhavalSolanki how are you ? do you have solution ?
